# Strip off guids from urls using gtag client (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics

My page urls look like this

- /GUID/profile/GUID
- /delete?profile=GUID

I would like to strip off all the GUID from URL before sending to the server. This should not break the funnel or goal setting too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '**Search and Replace**' Filter:

[image]